# How to add a property with the same name in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

So I am using a component framework for Vue2 named [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) and I am having a problem regarding the class of the input textbox.

So in the textbox component, the code is:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div(
    class="input-group"
    v-bind:class="classes"
  )
    label(
      v-bind:for="id"
      v-html="label"
    )
    input(
      v-bind:id="id"
      v-bind:name="name"
      v-bind:placeholder="placeholder"
      v-bind:required="required"
      v-bind:type="type"
      v-bind:value="inputValue"
      ref="input"
    )
</template>
```

Now I want to add a class in the text input because I want it to be a date and I am using the [flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/) plugin. The name of the class is flatpickr. So the way I use the component is like this:

```
<v-text-input id="someID" label="SomeLabel" v-model="someModel"></v-text-input>
```

And if I try to add the class random I do it like this:

```
<v-text-input id="someID" label="SomeLabel" v-model="someModel" class="flatpickr"></v-text-input>
```

The code isn't working because the class goes to the div. I checked the code generated in the elements of chrome and it looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group flatpickr" data-v-3eb87e8e="">
   <label for="SomeLabel">SomeLabel</label>
   <input id="someID" type="text">
</div>
```

As you can see, the class goes to the class of the div. What's the best way/trick to add a class in the text input? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean the code isn't working? what's your expectation? to select the element with JS? or you just want to change the css style?

Comment: @Sabrina check my updated post..

Comment: do you mind to introduce the external component? https://github.com/jrainlau/vue-flatpickr

Comment: @Sabrina that component has it's own datepickr component and I can't properly copy the design of my input text that's why im using the main library instead

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same CSS property, by giving path of your input like following:

```
.random input{
    height: etc;
}
```

**Edit**

Given that you are also getting id of the input box, to apply the class on specific input, you can also use the id:

```
.random #someid{
    height: etc;
}
```

Comment: I will only add classes to specific inputs

Comment: @FewFlyBy I have updated the answer, does it cover your use-case or what this not covers.

Answer (score 1):

to add the class into `<div>` tag is the design of Vue, the class added into components will be rendered into the top level of the element in the template.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#With-Components

If you want to apply the css to `<input>`, you can simply do:

```
.random input {
  /* your css style */
}
```

If you want to use flatpickr with vuejs, you can try to use this `vue-flatpickr` component, https://github.com/jrainlau/vue-flatpickr

Comment: Updated my post